# Vim search and replace variable number of lines

Tags: vim

I have some text where there are two columns and two or more of rows. The first column name is printed only once. Thereafter, it is left blank for subsequent rows, until it is changed again.

e.g.

```
name1 xxx 
      zza 
      yyy
      zzz
name2 ggg
      xxx
name3 xxx
      zza
      ggg
      yyy
      zzz
```

I want to change the above to print the column name in all rows, as follows:

```
name1 xxx 
name1 zza 
name1 yyy
name1 zzz
name2 ggg
name2 xxx
name3 xxx
name3 zza
name3 ggg
name3 yyy
name3 zzz
```

Note: as mentioned in the beginning, the number of lines with blank for first column is variable. Can be any number above 2.

The following pattern will work if applied repeatedly:

```
:%s/\(^\S\+ \)\(.*\n\)\s\+/\1\2\1/
```

But of course, that will only change one line at a time, and I have to repeat it until all matches are updated.

My question: Is there a single command to accomplish the above mentioned transformation where the number of lines are variable.

Comment: instead of '%' you can specify the line numbers of which you want to operate.
Ex: `:12,16s/toto/titi/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  pattern is  almost working,  the main  problem is  that since  you
replace the newline this changes the  lines and that's why you'd need to
run multiple times, as you described. When you remove the next line, the
cursor will jump  it (even though it  is replaced back in)  and then you
can't match.

You can  fix this easily  by "starting" the  match only at  the relevant
part, with  the [`\zs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Czs) flag which  is very useful. The  [`\v`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) is
also useful  to make  the pattern more  readable, controlling  the magic
option. This should work:

```
:%s/^\v(\S+\s+).*\n\zs\s+/\1
```

It captures the  non-blank part, moves to the next  blank line start and
sets the match there. Then replaces with the captured part. Now when the
cursor moves,  the process will  be repeated  and if the  following line
does not begin  blank (such as in  the beginning of the  new group) then
nothing happens because it is not a match.

Answer (score 0):

you can record the same logic to a macro, in this case q.

`qq:%s/\(^\S\+ \)\(.*\n\)\s\+/\1\2\1/` press return and q again to stop recording the macro

@q will run it once, but if you know the maximum number of line (eg:10), you can run 10@q

Comment: 4@q will fix your example in the question. Also there is no harm in having a high number like 1000@q. It will still do what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. I used macros to repeatedly issue the command. See sidyll answer for a single command.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` for this can be a solution:

```
:%!awk '{if($2==""){$2=$1;$1=name}else{name=$1};print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with this little Python script, provided all the whitespace are spaces and not tabs:

**col.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    if not line.startswith(" "):
            current = line.split()[0]
            print(line, end="")
            continue
    print(line.replace(" " * len(current), current, 1), end="")
```

Then pipe the text file to the script:

```
python col.py < text.txt
```

ViM can be compiled with Python support, so something like this could potentially be used within ViM.